# First Order formula Validity?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, first-order-logic

The given first order formula is valid or not?

[ β→ ∃ₓ α(x) ]→ [ ∀ₓ(β→α(x)) ]

Someone please answer this, I have been Struggling to know the correct answer to this Question?

Intuitively it seems to be a valid formula. However I am not sure!

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: Consider some simple (say, two-element) examples. E.g. what if there are two elements, $\alpha$ holds on both elements, and $\beta$ is false? What if there are two elements, $\alpha$ holds on one but not the other, and $\beta$ is true? Etc. Not only will this help you answer your question, checking small models is a good exercise anyways for developing intuition.

Comment: @lemontree In my opinion it is a valid formula.

Comment: @Noah what do you think, is it valid?

Comment: Try some examples. At least try the two I mentioned in my comment above! Checking examples yourself is an important part of building intuition; having someone tell you the answer isn't going to help you as much.

Comment: @Noah.. I have been pondering over this problem for last 3 hours. And as per my understanding It is valid. But one of my teacher said it is invalid and had shown me a mathematical proof. So because of this dilemma. I wanted to know whether my intuition is correct or not

Comment: @user7184691 For the third time: **try my examples**. It won't take long and I promise you'll learn something valuable once you work through them. Just knowing the answer is not going to be very helpful in the long run.

Comment: @user7184691 "one of my teacher said it is invalid and had shown me a mathematical proof" Wait, if you've seen a proof that it's wrong you should know that your intuition is not right. Maybe if you clarify *why* you think it's a valid formula, we can give useful responses.

Comment: @Noha if I consider your example i.e beta as false.. then formula is certainly going to be valid.

Comment: @user7184691 Great, you've solved the **first** example. What about the **second**? That is, where $\beta$ is true and $\alpha$ holds on one element but not the other?

Comment: But if we consider beta True, and alpha False. Then RHS becomes false. And therfore LHS could be True

Comment: So finally LHS is true and RHS false.. hence it is a invalid formula :D

Comment: Thanks Noah. Because of you I was able to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

As was discussed in the comments, the formula in question is **not** valid. Any model in which $\beta$ is true and $\alpha$ holds of some but not all elements will witness this.

---

Let me say a bit about how one might search for such a countermodel, since this is a skill it can take some time to develop. We start thinking about the *simplest* component of our formula, namely $\beta$ (it's just true or false, full stop - it doesn't involve thinking about elements of our model). So we think for a moment about the two possibilities for $\beta$ and how they would impact the model. Since it's easy to see that making $\beta$ false makes the whole formula true (since both antecedent and consequent will be vacuously true), we know we want $\beta$ to be **false** in our countermodel.

Now what about $\alpha$? Unlike with $\beta$, this is a bit more complicated. Essentially we have three choices: $\alpha$ holds always, $\alpha$ holds never, or $\alpha$ holds sometimes but not always.$^*$ We could whip up and check examples of all three possibilities separately, but the third should stand out as particularly promising. This is because the formula involves comparing an "$\exists_x$" and a "$\forall_x$." In the first two cases for $\alpha$, these don't behave differently since all elements of the domain will look alike; in the third case however there is differentiation between them (e.g. "$\exists_x\alpha(x)$" is true but "$\forall_x\alpha(x)$" is false). So the third seems to have the most promise, and we try it and see that it works.

---

$^*$OK, that's not totally true. Each of those cases is itself a rather wide umbrella: e.g. "$\alpha$ holds sometimes and fails sometimes" includes "$\alpha$ holds of one element and fails of two," and "$\alpha$ holds of forty elements and fails of seventeen," or ... However, the formula doesn't suggest that this will be important: since **we never consider *two* variables**, so multiplicity doesn't matter. For this reason we should look at the simplest possible examples of each case: for the first two cases this is a model with one element, and for the third case this is a model with two elements.